# Trying to understand custom properties added to JavaScript system object

Tags: javascript

I am new to web programming; trying to add custom properties to Javascript in-build object. The below code works as expected.

```
window.myName = "John 1";
alert(window.myName);  // Displays 'John 1'
```

However, the below code displays 'Undefined', would like to understand why it so?.

```
window.myName.lastName = "John 2"; 
alert(window.myName.lastName); // Displays 'Undefined', why?
```

Comment: I wonder how you missed that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'lastName' of undefined`

Comment: The cause of this behaviour is mentioned in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects. The statement `window.myName.lastName = "John 2"` generates a temporary `String` object that wraps the value of `window.myName`. The property `lastName` of this temporary object is set to `"John 2"`, the literal string stored in `windows.myName` is not affected. The temporary object vanishes as the statement completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `undefined` is because you define an string not an object in the first step:

```
window.myName = "John 1";
```

`myName` is defined, but is a string var, not an object, thus is can not have properties as you can read in [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)

Knowing this.... you can get your expected result defining `myName` as an object:

```
window.myName = {}
window.myName.lastName = "John 2";
```

You will get a result when

```
window.myName.lastName
```

OUTPUT:

```
"John 2"
```

Comment: I think OP expected the string to act like an object, something which your answer doesn't cover

Comment: I'd also add that OP can use `window.myName = new String("John 1")`, in which case he/she can assign properties

Answer (score 1):

You are adding property in object that object is not defined so first defined object and after add dynamic property. Check below-

```
if(typeof window.myName ==="undefined") {
    window.myName = {};  // If object is not defined then define empty object myname
}
window.myName.lastName = "John 2"; 
alert(window.myName.lastName); // Now it will show John2
```